# GNOME shell login issues

Tags: gnome, login

So, I've been messing around with IOMMU (AMD-Vi) to see if 18.04 fixed it and it didn't. Since I had a lot of homework to do, I didn't have the patience to make backups, serves me right (I only salvaged the /home directory intact from the drive before reinstalling). Now, if I leave it at auto-login, it logs in, but into the Xorg session, while I want Wayland, so I tried to change sessions, but lo and behold, it didn't work. It first said that there was something wrong, but upon reentering my password, I was left at the purple screen with nothing other than a pointer (regardless of session chosen in the menu, if I log out, I need to restart or use `startx` in another terminal to get back in). I already changed the owner of everything in the /home directory, including it, to me (sandy) and removed .Xauthority and .ICEauthority later, but to no avail. Is there any way to make it work short of another fresh install or upgrade (it's six months away, so yeah).

Comment: When you say "reenter the password" do you mean the first time it said password was invalid?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, even though it as valid (and yes, I checked Mum lock and Caps lock).

Comment: P.S. Just realized I misspelled Num lock. (facepalm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known bug, more info can be found in the bug report.
Workaround is doing cancel when you see the wrong password error message for now. And enter the right credentials.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1766137

Comment: Yeah, after an hour or two of using the session (watching a few episodes of Yu-Gi-Oh), it was working. I also discovered just now that, if I stay logged in on another terminal, it works (had to go back to Xorg to reinstall NetBeans). Thank you for the information!

Comment: @SandyVujaković An additional way of thanking Bart is to click the up-arrow next to his answer and he will get 10 points. This is what I have just done. You will notice a "1" next to his answer signifying 1 up-vote.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I assumed it would do that automatically with the declaration of its new status (accepted). Just did that as well. On a seperate note, why'd you remove your answer?

Comment: @SandyVujaković The voting system is confusing here for all new users. I deleted my answer because I didn't think it was helpful under this question. I thought it was more of a good answer searching for the right question :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Oh, OK. Well, still appreciated. Do you know anything about Ubuntu networking? If you do, check out my latest question.

Comment: @SandyVujaković I just undeleted the answer to quench the curiosity of others reading our comments. Afraid I haven't gotten into Ubuntu Networking yet.

Comment: I can report that it's fixed now. Yay! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you select the desktop environment and signing on with a valid password it can tell you it's invalid. When you enter the password a second time the error message goes away but it boots to a different desktop environment than you selected.

After typing your password a second time you have to click on the gear icon to reselect your desktop environment before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the password:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 signon 5 desktops.png]

Comment: No, it doesn't enter ANY desktop if I reenter the password. Anyway, it sometimes works regardless and it always works if I'm logged into another console/terminal (I prefer tty3).

Comment: @SandyVujaković I'm not saying it enters a desktop. I'm saying it **will not** enter a desktop because the selection changes to an invalid one. After the second time of entering your password, before pressing enter, click the gear and select a valid desktop because an invalid one becomes the default at the same times it tells you your password is invalid (which it wasn't). I'm sorry I'm not explaining myself clearly.

Comment: Well, it's irrelevant, since I'm in Wayland and am not moving from it (touchpad gestures in GNOME3) and when I do have to go to Xorg for a bit, I'll just press "Cancel" at the right time. Thank you anyway!